# javascript scope and on jquery's $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

In the following example, can someone explain why var1 is recognized and var2 is not?
Why are the first and second treated as different scopes if they refer to the same event on the same DOM element?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var1 = 12;      // no var =global
    var var2 = 24;  // local
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log(var1);  // = 12
    console.log(var2);  // fail

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how scoping works in JavaScript.

Without `var`, it's always property assignment. The implicit object is `window`.

It has nothing to do with events - which is part of the DOM, but not something that relates to JavaScript as a language.

Comment: I'm ok with usage of var. I am more interested in what is considered different scope.  Don't the two functions get merged together because they refer to the same event on the same DOM element?

Comment: @Abe Nope. They are two different functions, just bound to the same event. JavaScript (the language, not jQuery, not DOM) has no idea about what a DOM event is). The last sentence of my answer makes that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `var var2` to declare `var2` it is considered as a local variable, where as var1 is considered as a declared in the global scope.

Since javascript has functional scope, any variable declared within the functional scope will be available only within it

Answer (score 0):

var2 is considered in a different scope because it is local to another function than the one it is called from, it doesn't have anything to do with the `.ready` event. as in:

```
(function(){
    var v = 1;
})();
//v outside that function is undefined. if you try to call it, it will return an undefined error
```

it is a matter of local / global variable .. please read more about the differences between them .. they exist in every programming language

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/n9PhS/)